# Libre-Office: insert one of two(or more) images depending on condition

Tags: image, text, insert, conditional-statements, libreoffice

Hi I was searching around to no avail on this topic.
I have a lot of documents that should have an image in the header.

Depending on a specific condition I want to insert image1.png or image2.png

Up to now I have two versions of the document but I have to re-edit two documents when something changes which is a drag.

I know how to insert text depending on a condition but I couldn't manage it to work with images. I am aware of the implicatoins regarding linked images.

I think the field should look something like:

```
conditional text operator="qmfy" {img:../ressources/image1} : {img:../ressources/image2}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have two hidden paragraphs in header. First with condition hideImage==2 and second with condition hideImage==1. Then you anchor two images to those paragraphs. Then depending on variable hideImage one image (paragraph) is hidden.

Comment: Axel Richter: Your proposal actually worked. Thanks for the hint on sections. It took me some time to get it running, because I have a (more or less) new installed laptop and JRE was not installed. But the libreoffice suite relys on JRE regarding these funtions. So it took me a while to find out why it wasn't working. After having installed JRE it worked.

Comment: F*ck! After all I had to find out that it DOES NOT WORK. Finally I have to export the document to a PDF, but the conditional sections are not exported. I.e. the important stuff is missing. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Works for me. See detailed description below. Have you changed properties for PDF export? Are you possibly exporting Range Selection only?

Comment: The problem is - as far as I've found out: The conditional section MUST contain text. In my case it's just images. I added some dummy text with a white colored font on a white background and it worked.... Thanks for your help Axel Richter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detailed description:

- open new Writer document
- insert header (Insert - Header - Default Style)
- insert two paragraphs in header
- select first paragraph in header
- insert a hidden paragraph field (Insert - Field - Others- Functions -
  Hidden Paragraph) with condition showImage!=1 (so this paragraph is
  hidden if showImage!=1)
- press [Ctrl]+[F9], so that you see the fields
- select second paragraph in header
- insert a hidden paragraph field (Insert - Field - Other- Functions - 
  Hidden Paragraph) with condition showImage!=2 (so this paragraph is
  hidden if showImage!=2)
- select the paragraph in document body
- insert a variable field showImage with value 1 (Insert - Field -
  Other - Variables - Name:=showImage Value:=1)
- place the cursor to the end of the first hidden paragraph in header
- insert a image there
- place the cursor to the end of the second hidden paragraph in header
- insert a image there
- press [Ctrl]+[F9] (now only the first image should be visible)
- change the value of the variable showImage to 2
- now only the second image should be visible
- save the file

This document, which is created as described above, is exportable as a PDF for me. It is then outputted as shown in the page preview.

Greetings

Axel